# RxJs -- Aggregate Events Every Second and Reset Scan

Tags: rxjs

I'm trying to create an observable that aggregates events *within* the scope of a minute-- but i cant get the aggregations to reset.

```
const events = new Rx.Subject();

// example
// create a reactive stream of BTC completed transactions
// aggregate the highs/lows over one second
const btc = events
    .filter(f => f.product_id === "BTC-USD" && f.type === "done")
    .window(Rx.Observable.interval(1000))
    .mergeAll()
    .scan((acc, i) => {
        //console.log(i);
        let price = i.price;
        if (i.price) {
            if (acc.high === -1 || price > acc.high) acc.high = price;
            if (acc.low === -1 || price < acc.low) acc.low = price;
            acc.last = price;
        }
        return acc;
    }, { high: -1, low: -1, last: -1, ts: (new Date()).getTime().toString() })
    .window(Rx.Observable.interval(1000))
    .map(j=> j.last())
    .mergeAll();

// output the stream of aggregates every second
btc.subscribe(j=>console.log(j));
```

Since i have a timestamp in the aggregation accumulator, i can tell that we're persisting the aggregation across windows.

```
{ high: '14725.97000000',
  low: '14106.01000000',
  last: '14150.52000000',
  ts: '1514089269250' }
{ high: '17279.27000000',
  low: '14059.87000000',
  last: '14162.09000000',
  ts: '1514089269250' }
```

How to reset scan? Or achieve the same thing via other means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the first `mergeAll` and the `scan` with a `mergeMap` - within which the `scan` is performed:

```js
const btc = events
    .filter(f => f.product_id === "BTC-USD" && f.type === "done")
    .window(Rx.Observable.interval(1000))
    .mergeMap(w => w.scan((acc, i) => {
        let price = i.price;
        if (i.price) {
            if (acc.high === -1 || price > acc.high) acc.high = price;
            if (acc.low === -1 || price < acc.low) acc.low = price;
            acc.last = price;
        }
        return acc;
      }, { high: -1, low: -1, last: -1, ts: (new Date()).getTime().toString() })
    )
    .window(Rx.Observable.interval(1000))
    .map(j=> j.last())
    .mergeAll();
```

Also, if you use `reduce` instead of `scan`, the second `window`, etc. should not be needed, as `reduce` will emit only the last value:

```js
const btc = events
    .filter(f => f.product_id === "BTC-USD" && f.type === "done")
    .window(Rx.Observable.interval(1000))
    .mergeMap(w => w.reduce((acc, i) => {
        let price = i.price;
        if (i.price) {
            if (acc.high === -1 || price > acc.high) acc.high = price;
            if (acc.low === -1 || price < acc.low) acc.low = price;
            acc.last = price;
        }
        return acc;
      }, { high: -1, low: -1, last: -1, ts: (new Date()).getTime().toString() })
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think we don't need scan here If i understand your task correctly. Try this example:

```
var openings = Rx.Observable.interval(3000);

// Convert the window to an array
var source = Rx.Observable.timer(0, 100)
    .window(openings)
    .take(3) // restrict values just for example
    .flatMap(function (x) { 
    let arrayedValues = x.toArray();
    //Here you can caluculate high, low, last, ts
    return arrayedValues; 
    });

source.subscribe(
(x) => console.log(x)
```

[plunker](http://jsfiddle.net/Kievsash/9mcmju95/3/)

Comment: FYI, `toArray` [is implemented](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.5.6/src/operators/toArray.ts#L9-L11) using `reduce` - which is what I suggested using in my answer. As usual, there are multiple ways of doing something in RxJS :)

Comment: More about RxJS in my video-course: https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/hands-rxjs-web-development-video